# RegEx with multiple Var variable

Tags: c#, regex, var

If you guys decide to put this code into your complier, you will notice that I get a `Implicitly-typed local variables must be initlialized` error on the `var match`. But i'm not too sure about how to go about doing this check (for text.count()) any other way. Sometimes my OCR will miss a letter or something and if it does, the number of characters will be less and that will make the `match` variable return a null...leaving me without a result.

Also, for bonus points, anyone that can help clean up my REGEX expression that'd be nice..i just started using it recently and i'm not tooo skilled in the semantics yet.

```
var match;
if (wordList[i].Text.Count() < 12)
{
    match = Regex.Match(wordList[i].Text, @"c[:;i]ty[!l1;:i/][5s][tuj!l/]z[i;:l]p[c1:;zs]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
else
{
    match = Regex.Match(wordList[i].Text, @"c[:;i]ty[!l1;:i/][5s][tuj!l/][f!l1j;:i/]z[i;:l]p[c1:;zs]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
if (match.Success)
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't declare a `var` without initializing it. Use

```
Match match;
```

Or if you really must,

```
dynamic match;//I don't recommend this
```

[Var](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) is an implicitly typed variable, you must give it the value for it to infer the actual type. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx).

Comment: well I understand that. But doing `var match = null;` doesn't work. I know there has to be a way to do this.

Comment: @MaylorTaylor by doing var match = null you're still not telling the compiler what type match is.

Comment: You can't give a variable of type `var` a null type. Declare match as type `Match`. Edit: Yuriy beat me D:

Comment: @MaylorTaylor There is a way to do it and it's to tell the compiler what type `match` is by doing `Match match;` as this answer says.

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx).

> Beginning in Visual C# 3.0, variables that are declared at method
>   scope can have an implicit type var. An implicitly typed local
>   variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type
>   yourself, but the compiler determines the type.

When you declare a variable, you need to use explicitly typed way, or do

```
var match = new Match();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the compiler something so it can infer what the type is. For example this will work:

```
var match = (Match)null;
```

Because the compiler knows `var` is supposed to be a `Match`.

Why you would want to do this over `Match match;` is beyond me, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your regex patterns, I'll suggest that you could break your code down by separating the "pattern decision logic" from the rest of your code.

Below I've provided 2 separate examples for how to break this down.  The first defines a `DeterminePattern` method that just returns which string to use as the regex pattern.  The second defines a `FindMatch` method that returns the appropriate Match object.

Technically, either of these allows you to continue to use the var keyword, but in my mind that's not really that important...the benefit here, as I see it, is making the code simpler to read and understand.  You can decide for yourself whether breaking the code down like this achieves that.

**Example 1**

```
private static string DeterminePattern(string input)
{
    if (input.Count() < 12)
    {
        return @"...";
    }

    return @"...";
}


var match = Regex.Match(wordList[i].Text, DeterminePattern(wordList[i].Text), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (match.Success)
{ ... }
```

**Example 2**

```
private static Match FindMatch(string input)
{
    if (input.Count() < 12)
    {
        return Regex.Match(input, @"...", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }

    return Regex.Match(input, @"...", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}

var match = FindMatch(wordList[i].Text);
if (match.Success)
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it **DRY**: Don't Repeat Yourself.

If you must use `var` (and even if you don't: what's the point of using `var` in this context especially?), this construct is better:

```
string text = wordList[i].Text ;
string pattern = text.Length < 12
               ? @"c[:;i]ty[!l1;:i/][5s][tuj!l/]z[i;:l]p[c1:;zs]"
               : @"c[:;i]ty[!l1;:i/][5s][tuj!l/][f!l1j;:i/]z[i;:l]p[c1:;zs]"
               ;
Match match = Regex.Match( text , pattern , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase ) ;
```

Or, better yet:

```
string text  = wordList[i].Text ;
Regex  rx    = text.Length < 12 ? Regex1 : Regex2 ;
Match  match = rx.Match( text , pattern , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase ) ;
.
.
.
private static readonly Regex1 = new Regex( @"c[:;i]ty[!l1;:i/][5s][tuj!l/]z[i;:l]p[c1:;zs]" , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase ) ;
private static readonly Regex2 = new Regex( @"c[:;i]ty[!l1;:i/][5s][tuj!l/][f!l1j;:i/]z[i;:l]p[c1:;zs]" , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase ) ;
```

And why on earth are you using Linq (`Wordlist[i].Text.Count()`) to get the length of a string? Strings already know length. There's no need to iterate over it to count characters: just ask the string how long it is by querying its `Length` property.